# What's the proper elitist equivalent for the word "slut"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the posh word for a slut? I have ruled out prostitute, whore, hooker and call girl. I want a posh word for *slut* which sounds elitist and is very esoteric.

Characteristics for the sluts in my fiction:

> They are strong and don't feel ashamed of their job.

*Elites* in my book are people who work in the shadows and thereby ultimately control the fate and all the actions of all humanity. People who aren't elite in my book are basically just puppets.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32534/discussion-on-question-by-frosty-the-dopeman-whats-the-proper-elitist-equivalen).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polite name for a prostitute](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211193/polite-name-for-a-prostitute).

Answer (score 3):

Graffito nailed it in his comment: *demimondaine* is the perfect word in this instance. It meets or exceeds your stated requirements.

Quoting from Wikipedia,

> Externally, the defining aspects of the demimonde were an extravagant lifestyle of fine food and clothes, often surpassing that of other wealthy women of their day with a steady income of cash and gifts from their various lovers. Internally, their lifestyle was an eclectic mixture of sharp business acumen, social skills, and hedonism. The smart demimondaine, like the fictional Gigi's grandmother, would invest her wealth for the day when her beauty would fade. Others ended up penniless and starving when age took its toll on their beauty unless they managed to marry.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demimonde

Comment: Thanks Mark. I agree it's sounds and feels good to use at the moment. Anyways thank you all for putting some time for my question.